# Was Return of the Jedi released in Japan as Revenge of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, production, translation

As is commonly known, the working title of *Return of the Jedi* was, for some time, *[**Revenge** of the Jedi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi#Title_change)*. This was even used on early promotional material and on a teaser trailer.

In this video by [Techmoan](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5I2hjZYiW9gZPVkvzM8_Cw) on the old video format VHD, his copy of *Return of the Jedi* seems to bear the correct title in English, while the Japanese title translates to ***Revenge** of the Jedi*.

*(Skip to 15:30)*

I can easily imagine a scenario where the working title (*Revenge of the Jedi*) was translated to Japanese, then changed to *Return of the Jedi* without retranslating it.

**Was at any point in time, *Return of the Jedi* released as *Revenge of the Jedi* in Japan?**

Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Based on a very brief look at covers, it looks like posters were released that said "Revenge of the Jedi". When the film was retitled,  the Japanese text wasn't changed since the word used isn't a literal translation. My Japanese isn't up to the task of answering this properly, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, the title was changed quite late in the production process. Apparently, George Lucas sold off posters with the Revenge-title to members of the fan club. I also once saw a jacket with that title on an episode of _Storage Wars_.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of return revenge? As they show in every movie.

Comment: @ManojKumar: Uh ... no? Return can simply mean return to power, return into one's previous position, return into the system, etc. It does not imply any particular interaction with whoever interrupted the protagonists' maintained presence (or whether that was anyone's fault at all).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The writing on the <s>DVD</s> VHD case in your picture says "ジェダイの復讐" (Jedi no fukushu), which indeed means "Revenge of the Jedi." (ジェダイ is "Jedi" spelt phonetically, whereas "[復讐](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%BE%A9%E8%AE%90)" means revenge.)

The [Japanese Wikipedia page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA_%E3%82%A8%E3%83%94%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%896/%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%B8%B0%E9%82%84) appears to say that it was released as ジェダイの復讐 originally and later changed to its current title, ジェダイの帰還 (Jedi no kikan), which means [Return](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%B8%B0%E9%82%84) of the Jedi. Part of it says (translation courtesy of Janus Bahs Jacquet in the comments):

> In America the original publication title was Return of the Jedi, while in Japan the original publication title was Revenge of the Jedi, but later on both were changed to the current title

So it seems that it was called ジェダイの復讐 (revenge) for some time in Japan before being changed to ジェダイの帰還 (return). The page goes on to discuss the reasons for the change, and you can get some of the meaning of it from a [Google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fja.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F%25E3%2582%25B9%25E3%2582%25BF%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%25BB%25E3%2582%25A6%25E3%2582%25A9%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2582%25BA_%25E3%2582%25A8%25E3%2583%2594%25E3%2582%25BD%25E3%2583%25BC%25E3%2583%25896%2F%25E3%2582%25B8%25E3%2582%25A7%25E3%2583%2580%25E3%2582%25A4%25E3%2581%25AE%25E5%25B8%25B0%25E9%2582%2584&edit-text=&act=url) of the page.

---

ETA: Since I was curious I asked a Japanese person. She says she remembers it as ジェダイの復讐 (Revenge of the Jedi), and never heard it in Japanese as ジェダイの帰還 (Return of the Jedi) until just now when she looked it up online. But she said she also knew it by its English title, Return of the Jedi. Valorum posted some links in the comments to materials from 1983 that say "Return of the Jedi" in English, but "ジェダイの復讐" in Japanese, like this:

[image]

After reading the Japanese Wikipedia page, my Japanese friend told me the  Japanese title wasn't changed until 2004, with the change being driven partly by fans asking for the name to be changed.

Comment: Actually, it's not a DVD; it's a **VHD**.

Comment: A more precise translation would be, “In America the original publication title was _Return of the Jedi_, while in Japan the original publication title was _Revenge of the Jedi_, but later on both were changed to the current title”. Not entirely sure what precisely these _publication titles_ are, though—they might just be the first title published, or they may have been the official titles of the movie when it came out.

Comment: You might find this interesting - From the Star Wars Scrapbook; https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBnaY.jpg + https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZzoH.png. The latter is a cinema ticket

Answer (score 22):

The film was released as "Return of the Jedi" but some of the posters had the older title "Revenge of the Jedi".

> The original teaser trailer for the film carried the name **Revenge of the Jedi**. In December 1982, Lucas decided that "Revenge" was not appropriate as Jedi should not seek revenge and returned to his original title. **By that time thousands of "Revenge" teaser posters (with artwork by Drew Struzan) had been printed and distributed.** Lucasfilm stopped the shipping of the posters and sold the remaining stock of 6,800 posters to Star Wars fan club members for $9.50.
>
> <sub><sup>**https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi#Title_change**</sup></sub>

**Sample Poster**

[image: Japanese Poster]

http://www.propstore.com/product/star-wars-ep-vi-return-of-the-jedi/large-japanese-revenge-of-the-jedi-poster/

**Based on IMDB article, it was not released in Japan as Revenge of the Jedi.**

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/releaseinfo

Comment: Notice that the famous "Revenge of the Jedi" poster is actually based on the Cloud City battle scene from The Empire Strikes Back, not anything from Return of the Jedi.

Comment: I intended to link to exactly that fragment of the Wikipedia article, but I see now I haven't. That Japanese movie poster is a good find, though. Its Japanese title seems to match with that on the cover of the VHD. I'll rewatch to see if it matches with the title on the booklet, since that's what he translated.

Comment: For me, what's more interesting is that the English title changed but the Japanese writing didn't.

Comment: I wonder how much those posters are worth now :o

Comment: @Valorum Judging by Japanese Wikipedia/Google searches, the "Japanese title" did also get updated at some point.

Comment: @Ixrec - It did, several years after the film was released

Comment: The IMDB link lists the Japanese title as "Sutâ wôzu/Jedai no fukushuu", which means "Star Wars / Revenge of the Jedi". (Though it was later changed to a Japanese title meaning "Return of the Jedi" - see my answer.)

Comment: @Valorum I’m at least as much intrigued (and horrified) that they’d release an official poster with the English title so atrociously kerned and spaced. (Though I have to admit that [some English ones](https://originalvintagemovieposters.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Return-of-the-Jedi-3225.jpg) weren’t much better.)

Answer (score 2):

The [article on Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA_%E3%82%A8%E3%83%94%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%896/%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%B8%B0%E9%82%84) (unedited translation of Google Translate) says:

> Originally published title in the United States was "Return of the
>   Jedi" ("Jedi's return"), **the original title published in Japan was
>   "Star Wars / Revenge of the Jedi**".

And further:

> However, in Japan, production of related products in the name of
>   "Revenge of the Jedi" has already progressed, and since they sought
>   impact subtitles aiming at box office success, **they were published as
>   [citation needed], "revenge of the Jedi"** in 1983 It was also followed
>   by the "special edition" published in 1997 [4]. In the summer of 2000,
>   fans of this series made a titlist signing campaign in Japan but it
>   did not come true [citation needed], the release of "Star Wars Trilogy
>   DVD - BOX" in 2004, finally translated the original in Japan "Return
>   of the Jedi" has been changed to.

As I understand from the text, the title "Return of the Jedi" was introduced in Japan in 2004.

Comment: "They were published as [citation needed]"? Man, I would have loved to get a poster of that! ...on a less flippant note, those "[citation needed]s" basically mean the Japanese wiki doesn't know either. The English one has a source for its claims.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The English page hase ZERO mentions of words with "japan"-root. So there is no a single evidence or reference about Japanese release on the English page.

Comment: I mean the English wiki has sources for the claims mentioned in the other answer, not pertaining specifically to the Japanese title/release. The fact that posters were produced in English with the other title is of course not direct evidence for anything released in Japan, nor did I mean to imply that.